# Request.post returns nothing

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I have very simple script, which should perform login process to webpage:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
credentials = {'user': 'user',
               'pass': 'pass'}
session = requests.Session()
req = session.get('https://myurl.com', verify=False)
html = BeautifulSoup(req.text)

login_form = html.find('form', {'name': 'loginForm'})
login_url = login_form['action']

# at this moment login_url has this form: https://myurl.com/webclient;jsessionid=AC7F87C5D38C0B2EABBF6D76379BB75B?pageid=816
req2 = session.post(login_url, data=credentials, headers=headers, verify=False)
print 'req2:', req2.text    # prints nothing
```

Why req2.text (although req2.status_code returns 200) is empty?
When I'm checking *action* atribute of *form* in html source I see URL without *jsessionid*. Why? And to which address should I send my credentials in request.post?

PS. *pageid* is generated dynamically, so this is the reason why I use BeautifulSoup to get this url from html form.

Comment: We don't know, and cannot know, without details on what server you are talking to here.. Servers are free to alter behaviour based on the headers and POST body is sent. The headers and body you send are somehow not deemed worthy compared to what your desktop browser sends. Perhaps you should try [Robobrowser](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to at least avoid missing out on any extra form fields present.

Comment: I checked and it works on Apache Tomcat/7.0.55. Thank you for hint about Robobrowser, I'll try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and it was really trivial - submit button value is mandatory in this case.
So all I need to do is just add button value to *credentials* dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the values:

```
credentials = {
      'user'.encode("utf-8"): 'user'.encode("utf-8"),
      'pass'.encode("utf-8"): 'pass'.encode("utf-8")
}
```

I trust you to write it better. I had the same problem and that was the solution.